# Wrap a request in a Soap Envelope?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, asmx

I have a request without the SOAP information, but I need to wrap it in a SOAP envelope.  In the past I have manually built the envelope using StringBuilder and put the request in the body, but is there a better, more generic way?  An example would be helpful.

Example:

I will have something like the following:

```
<UpdateQuantity>
   <Product id="1234"></Product>
   <Qty>10</Qty>
</UpdateQuantity>
```

So as I said above, I have just built the SOAP envelope using a StringBuilder and put the above xml in the body portion.  Is it best to just stick with that approach or is there a more generic way?  Should I write a method that takes all the SOAP parameters that can change with a request and still using a StringBuilder?

Comment: Don't you have access to the WSDL of the service? The best way would be to use "Add Service Reference" and point it to the WSDL. It will do all the work for you. Using a `StringBuilder` is one of the worst possible ways to do this.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I do not have access to the WSDL. In addition to that, the SOAP requests vary from client to client, so that is what I meant by generic. I know StringBuilder is not a good approach, hence the question I asked.

Comment: This is extremely strange. The entire basis of SOAP is the fact that SOAP requests are defined by the WSDL. You _really_ need to be given the WSDL. It need not be accessible online. They could email it to you.

Comment: If for some bizarre reason you are not using a WSDL and still pretending it's SOAP, then you should at least use LINQ to XML or XmlWriter or some other XML API to create the SOAP envelope (and, in fact, all of your XML). Don't use string APIs to create XML.

Comment: @JohnSaunders,  I can use LINQ to XML now, but before I was stuck in .NET 2 land.  Most of the time, we are not given a WSDL, just a technical document in which we have to manually construct the xsd's and go from there.

Comment: It amazes me. This is entirely your fault, for accepting this sort of "requirement". The people owning the service _have_ the WSDL, or _should_ have it. But since you don't demand it, you won't get it. We have standards for a reason, but if you don't require your partners use the standards, then it's just as though the standards don't exist.

Comment: @JohnSaunders,  you are on the verge of being very rude.  You are blaming me for something that you do not know the entire situation.  How do you know I didn't ask for it?  How do you know that I didn't gripe about it when I couldn't get it?  You are also assuming that I just started this from the beginning, these requirements where not set by me, they were set a long time ago by some who did not do a good job with the requirements.

Comment: I'm going to make this simple: say "no". Unless there is a good reason (like, "we're using PHP", or "we wrote the service by hand and it only _looks_ like SOAP"), then, for the sake of the Industry, you should simply not permit this. _Help_ them create and maintain a WSDL if necessary; _teach_ them why it's important, but don't permit this problem to grow worse. That's enough of this; it should be a blog post, and not a comment stream.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a service you need access to the service WSDL..isn't it? If it is a single service, How come requests  differs client to client?
The best way to me get your service wsdl and use axiom library to create standard soap messages..

Comment: We do not control the client requests (what the client sends us).  The requests are similar, but there is no standard that the clients have to adhere to.